# Symfony2.3 login in Internet Explorer or Safari

Tags: php, internet-explorer, symfony, safari

My doubt is about Symfony. I make this web http://trivialarbitros.tk/ and when try to access with email (abc) and password (abc) have success in chrome or firefox but don't work with IE or Safari. I try to find some log or some error but I can't find anything. Please can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use another server to log in: `http://159.149.130.120/ruben/final/web/app_dev.php/login`.
It is not right. Your cookies (and session) is set up to the `159.149.130.120` server but you want it would be available on the `trivialarbitros.tk`. If you want to do cross-domain authorization you need another approach. I recommend you to use only one server for all your logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot ¡¡¡¡¡ It is the problem.  I have to find other server.